# Mock System.Net.FtpClient GetHash method

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

Is it possible to mock `public FtpHash GetHash(string path)` of class `System.Net.FtpClient.IFtpClient`

The problem is that FtpHash has an internal constructor. Is there a way to mock it?

**Edit**

As part of the mock I would like to test all method code lines

```
    public bool Verify(string localFile, string removeFile)
    {
        bool res = false;
        using (IFtpClient client = new FtpClient())
        {
            var hash = client.GetHash(removeFile);
            if (hash != null)
            {
                if (hash.Verify(localFile))
                {
                    this.logger.Info("file pass Verify test");
                    res = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.logger.Error("file fail Verify test");
                }
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Thus hash.Verify should be able to return true/false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can mock the interface `IFtpClient` and the method `FtpHash GetHash(string path)` as well but you'll have to use reflection:

```
var ctor = typeof(FtpHash)
                 .GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)[0];
var ftphash = (FtpHash) ctor.Invoke(new object[]{ });

var fakeFtpClient = new Mock<IFtpClient>();
fakeFtpClient.Setup( x => x.GetHash(It.IsAny<string>()).Return(ftpHash);
```

**Edit:**

Based On the code you've provide you can't use moq at all.
You'll have to do some refactoring to be able to use it...(the code is coupled to `FtpClient`)

The reason for the exception at `hash.Verify` is simple:

The state of `m_algorithm`(private member of `FtpHash`) is `FtpHashAlgorithm.NONE`...([here is the source code](https://netftp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#System.Net.FtpClient/FtpHash.cs))

The setter of this member is internal so you'll have to use reflaction again and then use `deployitemattributte` to deploy the hashed file in the location of `localFile`.

IMO you shouldn't use moq at all in this scenario(the UT won't be small, readable, maintainable and fast unless you'll wrap the classes...). I offer you to use code weaving tool such as MsFakes/TypemMock ISolator. Then anything would be much simpler..(When I was in the .Net world I used MsFakes along with rhino mocks/moq...).

The following chart might help you with the solution strategy:

[image]

BTW the code looks like one of the cases where the code will never get any changes... I won't UT it at all... It just feels me like a waste of time...

Comment: Thanks. But then the function calls Verify(string file) and it throws exception :(

Comment: @AmirKatz sound weird... what exception do you face? I have to see your UT and the method under test to be able to point out the exception reason...(please add them)